# Typescript Structure dependent type signature

Tags: typescript, dependent-type

I'm trying to model a type that represent a collection on typed data (it will be loaded from a file) but without knowing the names of the fields ecc... How can I model something like that?? Example:

```
type Type = int | real | string;

type Signature = Map<string, Type>;

interface Data {
    signature: Signature;
    data: K[];
}
```

where the type K has all the properties in signature with the corresponding types:
ex. if

```
signature = [["a": real], ["b": string]];
```

all instances of K must have a field a of type real and a field b of type string.